# Odd rendering of models (one in front of the other)

Tags: libgdx

I have two models. One of my terrain, that is generated using a mesh. The other model (dark blue ocean) is a cylinder created using the ModelBuilder.

The ocean model and the terrain model intersect at the terrain's base. How do I stop these lines from happening?

[image]

Update:

I've added the attribute to my model :

```
modelBuilder.part("chunk" + Integer.toString(x) + "." + Integer.toString(y), myMesh, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material(new DepthTestAttribute(0)));
```

But now my model is gone, I am left with only the ocean.

```
oceanModel = mb.createCylinder(10000f, 15, 10000f , 30, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.NAVY)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the terrain to pass under the water (i.e., you put holes in the model where the water should show through), you can turn off depth testing while drawing these two meshes. If you are using the LibGDX 3D API, you can do this by giving the terrain model a DepthTestAttribute, with the attribute's `depthFunc` set to 0. If you are handling mesh rendering yourself, you can directly turn it off with `Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

If you do need the two meshes to intersect, then leave depth testing on, and you need to set the near plane of the camera to be farther away  (bigger number). Usually you should set it as far away as possible before it starts clipping objects in your game. It will also help to set the far plane of the camera to be closer, but not nearly as much as setting the near plane farther.

If you want to learn more about this issue, look up Z-fighting.

Comment: I've added the attribute to my model :
`modelBuilder.part("chunk" + Integer.toString(x) + "." + Integer.toString(y), myMesh, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material(new DepthTestAttribute(0)));`



But now my model is gone, I am left with only the ocean. 
`oceanModel = mb.createCylinder(10000f, 15, 10000f  , 30,  new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.NAVY)),
           Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates);`

Comment: The downside with turning off depth testing is that it also turns of depth writing, so anything drawn after your terrain will overwrite the pixels, regardless of whether the new mesh is actually closer to the camera or not. So if you use that method, you must force your meshes to draw in the order you want (water first, then terrain). This can be done by making your own RenderableSorter and giving it to ModelBatch. Or you could draw the ocean, flush the batch, draw the terrain, flush the batch, and then finally draw the rest of your stuff.

Comment: But then, let's say I want to models to intersect? Now they're drawing one over the other.

Comment: Did you try my second suggestion instead? The first method would only be helpful if you put holes in the terrain model where you want water to show through.

Comment: Oh geez, sorry about that. I'll try that later. Many thanks for the help Tenfour04, for this question and the prior ones.